# npm install warnings: babel warning message

Tags: npm, babeljs

My questions is what should I do with the warnings listed in the following output from npm install? It appears that the output message is asking me to run this command:

```
npm install babel-preset-env --save-dev
```

Is this the correct thing to do? Or can I ignore this. I am starting a React project and I do need babel functioning properly. Thank you.

Here's the output I get when I run npm install in my project directory:

> ```
> λ npm install
> npm WARN deprecated babel-preset-latest@6.14.0: We're super �  excited that you're trying to use ES2017+ syntax, but
>  instead of making more yearly presets � , Babel now has a better preset that we recommend you use instead: npm inst
> all babel-preset-env --save-dev. preset-env without options will compile ES2015+ down to ES5 just like using all the
>  presets together and thus is more future proof. It also allows you to target specific browsers so that Babel can do
>  less work and you can ship native ES2015+ to user � ! We are also in the process of releasing v7, so please give ht
> tp://babeljs.io/blog/2017/09/12/planning-for-7.0 a read and help test it out in beta! Thanks so much for using Babel
>  �, please give us a follow on Twitter @babeljs for news on Babel, join slack.babeljs.io for discussion/development
> and help support the project at opencollective.com/babel
> npm WARN deprecated babel-preset-es2017@6.24.1: �  Thanks for using Babel: we recommend using babel-preset-env now:
> please read babeljs.io/env to update!
> npm WARN deprecated babel-preset-es2016@6.24.1: �  Thanks for using Babel: we recommend using babel-preset-env now:
> please read babeljs.io/env to update!
> npm WARN deprecated babel-preset-es2015@6.24.1: �  Thanks for using Babel: we recommend using babel-preset-env now:
> please read babeljs.io/env to update!
> npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
> npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.0.14 (node_modules\react-scripts\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
> npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.0.14: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: >     {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
> npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.0.14 (node_modules\fsevents):
> npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.0.14: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: >     {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
> added 1143 packages in 409.143s
> ```

My environment:

- win7 ultimate x64 (SP1)
- npm v5.6.0
- code editor: VSCode v1.19.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That warning is because you `package.json` already lists other presets in it that are no longer recommended. Installing `babel-preset-env` and using it is the right thing to do, but you should still remove the other presets that it replaces.